# Why List view is not getting printed in the Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I have created and Application where I used SQLite UserDB database and I have Successfully inserted data in the User table now i need to print that Data in the Second Activity thus i am calling intent on my first page and using onclick listener I am going to next Activity where i have created and XML page like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".DisplayData">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
Now Using ArrayAdpater I need to print every user Data in to this Activity thus I created list_item.xml file for custom array adapter
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namelist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mustafa Dahodwala"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emaillist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mustafamandviwala45@gmail.com"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also in DisplayData.java file I have called and adapter which help me to interate through the list:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);

        MyDBHelper db=new MyDBHelper(this);
        ArrayList<DataModel> list=db.fetchuser();

        try {

            UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list);

            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MyError",e.toString());
        }



}
```

And the UserAdapter class is used to do so which I have called here

```
public class UserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {
private ArrayList<DataModel> list;
public UserAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<DataModel> list) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.list=list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView==null){
        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

    }
    TextView name=convertView.findViewById(R.id.namelist);
    TextView email=convertView.findViewById(R.id.emaillist);

    name.setText(list.get(position).name);
    email.setText(list.get(position).number);
    return convertView;
    }
    }
```

But When I run this App it doesn't show any error but also didn't display data in it I even check is my ArrayList is fetching data from database properly but yes It was doing its job correctly I dont know where am I going wrong please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi Mustafa first this code is really old and working on the main thread which is bad i recommend you use Room and Recycle view they work together beautifully  as for why you need to pass you array data to ArrayAdapter using in the constructor
`super(context, 0, list);`